# Special function

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(\overline{A})\subset\overline{f(A)}$. $\subset$ means $f(\overline{A})\neq\overline{f(A)}$.
Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Do you want that to hold for all $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ or will a single $A$ that works suffice?

Comment: Sorry. I am looking for just one $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. If you can give me a function which is holding it for all $A$ that would be cool aswell.

Comment: All $A$ is clearly not possible (in particular the inequality can _never_ hold for a finite $A$) -- but if you take $A=\mathbb R$ there are lots of possibilities.

Comment: There's no need to close the thread. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can only accept one answer per question, but you can upvote any you like. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Choose some $y$ that you want to be in $\overline{f(A)}$ but not in $f(\overline{A})$.  Now look for a function $f$ that takes values arbitrarily close to $y$ but not $y$ itself.

Comment: Hey, thank you for this hint. I tried following function: $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}$ and took $A=(2,\infty)$. We have $\overline{(2,\infty )}=[2,\infty ]$ of course and it's $1\in \overline{f(A)}$ but not in $f(\overline{A} )$. Can you tell me whether this is okay?

Comment: Yes, that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

For example,
$$ f(x)=\cases{x, x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
0, x \in \mathbb{R-\mathbb{Q} } } $$
$A=[0;1]$. $f(\overline{A})=[0;1]-\mathbb{Q}$. $\overline{f(A)}=[0;1]$

Comment: The first entry should be a $1$